# Make a search result a button; so that when clicked retrieves more information about the clicked item

Tags: php, sql

The following code is a basic search engine of my database. The user enters a description and it returns a pupil id, pupil forename and surname accordingly. I know wish to make the value of '$id' (which represents a pupil id) a link/button that when clicked will retrieve from the database more specific information about the projects that individual pupil has completed.

Thank you for your time. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
{if(isset ($_POST ['search'])){
    $searchq = $_POST['search'];
    $searchq= preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]#i","",$searchq);

    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pupil WHERE pupil_forename LIKE '%$searchq%' OR pupil_surname     LIKE '%$searchq%' OR pupil_id LIKE '%$searchq'") or die("Could not search");
    $count = mysql_num_rows($query);

    if ($count == 0 ) {
        $output = "No Pupils fit that description. Try again or add new Pupil details <a href='pupilinput.php'>here.</a>";     
    } else{
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
            $fname = $row['pupil_forename'];
            $sname = $row['pupil_surname'];
            $id = $row['pupil_id'];

            $output .= '<div> <b>ID:</b> '.$id.' <b>Name:</b> '.$fname.' '.$sname.'</div><br>';
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Okay, and your effort so far?

Comment: Well i have no idea where to start. Don't know what to do with the '$upn' variable. Haven't done anything like this before. Only basic search and retrieve engines.